# CoreStore insert array as relationship objects while updating data model

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, corestore

I have next code to update my workout:

```
func addMuscleGroups(muscleGroups: [MusclEntity], toWorkout: WorkoutEntity, completion: @escaping (ResultInfo<WorkoutEntity>) -> Void) {

        CoreStore.perform(
            asynchronous: { (transaction) -> WorkoutEntity? in
                let workout = transaction.edit(toWorkout)!

                for muscle in muscleGroups {
                    let editedMuscle = transaction.edit(muscle)!
                    workout.muscles?.insert(editedMuscle)
                }

                return workout
        },

            success: { (transactionWorkout) in // here we have muscles for transactionWorkout

                guard let unwrappedTransactionWorkout = transactionWorkout else {
                    return
                }

                let workout = CoreStore.fetchExisting(unwrappedTransactionWorkout) // there are no muscles objects

                guard let unwrappedWorkout = workout else {
                    return
                }

                completion(.data(unwrappedWorkout))
        },
            failure: { (error) in
                completion(.error(StackedError.internalFetchingDataError(message: error.debugDescription)))
        })

    }
```

But as I see I have inserted muscles while perform asynchronous block, but then when I do fetchExisting there are no muscles which were added in asynchronous block.

EDITED:

As I figured out there is missing relationships inverse in workout.muscles, now I added it and looks like CoreStore update workout entity correctly.

But now I have another problem if I call function few times:

1. first call

addMuscleGroups([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]...) 
print(unwrappedWorkout.muscles)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

2. second call addMuscleGroups([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]...)

   print(unwrappedWorkout.muscles)
   [6, 7]

(to simplify example I used 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 numbers), but there are MusclEntity objects actually

so as a result of second call of addMuscleGroups function unwrappedWorkout.muscles has two muscle objects instead of 7.

I've added short video:

https://www.screencast.com/t/63cRGKpk0Q

Comment: As your workout.muscles relationship is declared as optional ... did you check if it is not nil before doing insert(editedMuscle)

Comment: thnnks! yea it's not nil, I see that if we have no inversion in xcdatamodeld for some relationships than CoreStore want it map correctly. For example in my case `workout.muscles` relationship did not have inverse to `workout`. So I solve this problem by adding inverse and now it works. But I have another issue I updated my question

Comment: do we need to check for existing before inserting? as you see I used Swift Set instead of NSSet, which as I suppose can be overwriting totally

Comment: I've added a video of calling function (which I specified above) here:

https://www.screencast.com/t/63cRGKpk0Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered your question at [CoreStore's github](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore/issues/318) as well.

This would be the general behavior of `NSManagedObject`s with regards to to-many properties.

First, as you have found out, the inverse relationship is important.

Second, `Set` is not recommended for unordered `@NSManaged` properties. Using `NSSet` is recommended instead.
In that note, to-many relationships are treated as immutable, which means you cannot insert objects directly to the `NSSet` value. There are two ways you can insert values.

1. Assigning a new `NSSet` directly:

```swift
var muscles = (workout.muscles as! Set<MusclEntity>?) ?? []
muscles.insert(newMuscle)
workout.muscles = muscles as NSSet
```

2. Use KVO mutable accessors (creates an `NSMutableSet` proxy for you):

```swift
workout.mutableSetValueForKey(#keyPath(WorkoutEntity.muscles)) 
    .addObject(newMuscle)
```

Comment: I changed Swift.Set to NSSet of @NSManaged property and now your code works for me, thank you!

Comment: one thing I noticed that some guys suggest to use this: "generics by default, to-many relationships will be generated as NSSet?. But who can deal with typeless containers these days? Use the native Swift Set type instead:"

from this link https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/04/core-data-type-safety-with-swift/

anyway I switched to NSSet and all works.

Comment: Long time ago Xcode actually generated `Set<T>` for unordered relationships, but they found out it breaks Swift bridging as you have observed due to the dynamic behavior of the concrete `NSSet` subclass that Core Data uses. So they reverted it back to `NSSet`. I forgot where Apple documents this behavior but I think it’s in one of the past Xcode Release Notes

Comment: John I have posted answer, hope this may help someone some day. Just want you to take a look. So I used you've answered which works perfect, but this `workout.muscles = muscles as NSSet` very tricky for some cases, I highlights them in an answer. and as always thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I have `PlaylistEntity` and this is how my import looks like. This func is called when I do `transaction.importUniqueObject` for my playlist, what I want to do here is to import all needed properties of playlist and relationships (in this simple example called `songs`):

```
public func update(from source: ImportSource, in transaction: BaseDataTransaction) throws {
        self.id = id
        self.title = source["title"] as? String

        if let songsJsonArray = source["songs"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            let songs = try! transaction.importUniqueObjects(
                Into<SongEntity>(),
                sourceArray: songsJsonArray)

            for song in songs {
                self.mutableSetValue(forKey: #keyPath(Playlist.songs))
                    .add(song) // This code will insert new song to NSSet which is unique and can't be duplicated. 100% working code
            }

            // this code:
            // self.songs = NSSet(array: days)
            // actually will not work well for all cases I will explain below
        }
    }
```

Let's say you want to add few songs to playlist and you've called this function which update you local storage with new song by adding it to playlist and make request to the server:

```
inserNewSong(song1, toPlaylistWithId: someId_abc1)
inserNewSong(song2 toPlaylistWithId: someId_abc1)
inserNewSong(song3 toPlaylistWithId: someId_abc1)
```

So now your local storage has 3 songs in playlist. But we sill waiting for response form the server.

So each time songs is added on the server and server replied back, I reimport playlist using `update` func above.

The first response from the sever will return only one song in array, but as I mentioned my local storage already has 3 songs but this code `self.day = NSSet(array: days)` will replace 3 songs with just one.

Second response will return [song1, song2], and this code `self.day = NSSet(array: days)` will replace 3 songs with just 2.

For sure if you have quick connection and all 3 requests the the server finished immediately, you've probably will not see this effect, though I would like to use second approach suggested by @JohnEstropia:

```
self.mutableSetValue(forKey: #keyPath(Playlist.songs))
                        .add(song)
```